# iOS: Choose default calendar in the Settings Page

Tags: ios, calendar, settings

I want make a custom setting page of my app, letting the user to select the default calendar which my application should use.

I've created the settings section like [this tutorial](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/05/18/adding-a-settings-bundle-to-an-iphone-app.html), but i can't find the right key to use for allow the selection of the calendar!

I need this because in my application i show the calendar's events, and by default i show the event on the main calendar, but i want let to the user the selection of the calendar.

There is a way for do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The calendar is automatically set by the system. Why would a user of your app want to use a different calendar in the phone and in the app?

Comment: Because in my app he may want to use the "Work" calendar, while in the phone he want to use the "personal" calendar.

Comment: Oh… okay. I thought 'different calendars' as in Hindu calendar, Buddhist calendar, etc.

Comment: Not really, just different synced calendars. It's an application for business that let to edit and show events. Simply i want the user can select the default calendar to show. But only for my application, not for the entire system.